# ArcGIS Online: How to export layer data?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have created an application using ArcGIS Online. I have some layers in it. Now I want a complete report of all layers means I want to export/download layer data in any format.

So Is there any solution or APIs, through which we can query the layers and download the data?

Comment: Go-to my content and export them. If exported to shapefile, open relevant dbf in Excel etc.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to query an ArcGIS layer is by using the [REST API](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/get-started-with-the-services-directory.htm).

You didn't mention which technology your application is using, but assuming it's a web application, you should probably use the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. More specific: The [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-QueryTask.html) object can be used to query data from a layer.

Comment: Yes, It's a web application. I am able to query data from the layer. I have some fields in the layer. Basically, I need to download the whole data(all field data) of the layer in pdf or any other format. Can you suggest any solution for that?

Comment: If it has to be PDF, I don't think so. AGOL does not have a reporting facility (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012597), so you would have to use a 3rd party report generator, or try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript. If *any* format is fine, you could for instance use JavaScript to open a new window, write the results of the QueryTask to that window, and have a user save that to a file. Or perhaps have a Copy button that copies the data to the clipboard?